# nullptr can't use in valarray

Tags: c++, c++11

Why can't use nullptr in the constructor function?( the function name: Wine) When i try to do this, the program will break down and no any error report maybe because i don't the reason for that.

```
#ifndef WINE_H_
#define WINE_H_
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<valarray>
using std::string;
using std::valarray;
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Pair                                    //member of the wine
{
private:
    T1 a;
    T2 b;
public:
    T1 & first(){ return a; }
    T2 & second(){ return b; }
    T1 first()const{ return a; }
    T2 second()const{ return b; }
    Pair(const T1 & aval, const T2 & bval) :a(aval), b(bval){}
    Pair(){}
};
typedef valarray<int>ArrayInt;
typedef Pair<ArrayInt, ArrayInt>PairArray;

class Wine
{
private:
    string name;
    PairArray bt;
    int years;
public:
    Wine();                                          
    Wine(const char * a, int y,int b[], int c[]);    //no problem
    Wine(const char * a, int y);                    //here is that problem function
    void GetBottles();                              //no problem
    void Show()const;                               //no problem
    int Sum(){ return bt.second().sum(); }
};

Wine::Wine(const char * a, int y) :name(a), years(y), bt(ArrayInt(0, y), ArrayInt(0, y)){} 
**//When I am trying to use nullptr to instead 0 in the ArrayInt(0,y),the whole program will break down during work.**


Wine::Wine(const char * a, int y, int b[], int c[]) :bt(ArrayInt(b, y), ArrayInt(c, y))
{
    name = a;
    years = y;
}

Wine::Wine() :bt(ArrayInt(),ArrayInt())
{
    name = "null";
    years = 0;
}

void Wine::GetBottles()
{
    std::cout << "Please input the years and the bottles\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "input the year: ";
        (std::cin >> bt.first()[i]).get();
        std::cout << "input the bottles";
        (std::cin >> bt.second()[i]).get(); 
    }
}

void Wine::Show()const
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++)
    {
        cout << bt.first()[i] << '\0' << bt.second()[i] << endl;
    }
}

#endif

#include<iostream>                          //test part
#include"wine.h"

int main(void)
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << "Enter name of wine: ";
    char lab[50];
    cin.getline(lab, 50);
    cout << "Enter number of years: ";
    int yrs;
    cin >> yrs;

    Wine holding(lab, yrs);
    holding.GetBottles();
    holding.Show();
    return 0;

}
```

Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a funny one. The reason why it breaks in one example, but not another is following:

There are two different constructors for `std::valarray` (more than that, but those two matter):

```
valarray( const T& val, std::size_t count ); // 1
valarray( const T* vals, std::size_t count ); // 2
```

When you use 0 (`valarray(0, y)`) you are calling the first version - creating an array of `y` elements, where every element is initialized to 0.

But when you are calling it with `nullptr`, you are calling the second version of it - trying to initialize your new array with a copy from an array pointed to by the first argument to the constructor. But your first argument is `nullptr`, and any attempt to use at as an array triggers undefined behavior, and program crashes.